# How can achieve an iPhone home screen like reorganization feature?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a vertical UIScrollView just wide enough for a single column of buttons.  The buttons can be dragged by the user, but when one is being moved I want the other buttons to move up or down out of the way.  The only way that I can think of to do this is in the UIPanGestureRecognizer responsible for moving the button, every time its method gets called running a `for` loop in the subviews, checking the y values.  That seems incredibly inefficient, and would require keeping track of which buttons have already moved to prevent moving them more than once.  There has to be a better way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same functionality has been implemented in [this project](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView/) and in [this project also](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) . I hope project code will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok I downloaded both of them, but I can't run them for some reason.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, and I can build and run my other apps fine.  Just not those two for some reason

Comment: Ok, try this link https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView/downloads , download as zip n try again to run project

Comment: Just tried that, but I still got the same issue.  This is weird

Comment: If it makes any difference, when I go to the product menu in Xcode all of the top 5 options are greyed out, except for analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Your could use a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell. Just implement canMoveRowAtIndexPath, moveRowAtIndexPath and targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath on UITableViewDelegate

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified, these buttons can also be dragged out of their scrolling view to be placed in an adjacent view